# Custom Selection In Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am using C# and MS Sql Server R2. I have database table called `"Customer"` and here are the fields.

```
( CusId| FName | LName | Gender | Area | RegisterDate ).
-------------------------------------------------------
```

I hv created a small database application usign C# and Entity Framework.
My Winform has a datadridview. What I want to do is I want to bind the data form Customer table to that datagridview. But when it is binding some column data should be converted depending on a condition and some data just convert .
The datadridview columns are

```
(ID,Title,Name,Area,Reg Date)
-----------------------------
```

1. When it is binding the Name column should have the values
   concatenated FName + LName
2. Database column has stored the Gender as 'M' and 'F'. But when it
   bind to datagirdview it should become "Mr" and "Mrs" depending on
   the value.
3. Last thing is database column "RegisterDate" has datetime value. But
   it shoud be converted to only date (yyyy-mm-dd) format in
   datagridview.

Please tell me how to write LINQ query in C# using Entity framework to retrieve data correctly.
Help me to fix this mess. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from r in query
             select new {
                 ID = r.CustID,
                 Title = ?,
                 Name = r.Fname + " " + r.LName,
                 // ...
             };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, one of the options can be to create the DTO (Data Transfer Object )that will match your DataGridView layout.

e.g.

```
    class CustomerDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Area { get; set; }
        public string RegDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you fetch data from database with EF and select it into your DTOs.

Something like that:

```
        var customerDtos = context.Customers.ToList().Select(c=> new CustomerDto
        {
            Id=c.ID, Area = c.Area, Name = c.FName + " " + c.LName, RegDate = c.Date.Format("yyyy-MM-dd"), Title = c.Gender == "M" ? "Mr" : "Ms"
        });
```

Of course it would be a good idea to consider adding paging support, etc., but this is approximately what you need.
And then you bind the result to DataGridView

```
        dataGridView1.DataSource = customerDtos;
```

Comment: No problem, Glad it helped. If the problem is solved, would you be so kind to mark one of the answers as accepted :)

Comment: I would move the .ToList() behind the Select statement.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have following entity mapped to your database table:

```
class Customer
{
    public int CusId { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
}
```

Create view model which you will bind to your grid:

```
class CustomerModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string RegDate { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use some mapping library to map between these two entities. I recommend you to use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) (you can get it from NuGet). First step is creating map (usually this code added on start of application):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerModel>()
      .ForMember(cm => cm.ID, m => m.MapFrom(c => c.CusId))
      .AfterMap((c,cm) => {
            cm.Name = String.Format("{0} {1}", c.FName, c.LName);
            cm.Title = (c.Gender == "M") ? "Mr" : "Mrs";
            cm.RegDate = c.RegisterDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
      });
```

Then you will be able to map your database entities to models which will be displayed on UI:

```
 var customers = db.Customers.ToList(); // get customers from database
 var models = Mapper.Map<List<CustomerModel>>(customers);
 // then bind your grid to models
```